# Can a child use Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

My child, who is aged 8, wants to use Google Colab to explore Python and machine learning. When he tries to access it, he receives the error that:

"This service is unavailable for Google Workspace for Education users who are under 18 and children under 13 (or the age of consent in your country)."

His account is managed through Google Family Link, hence Google knows his age. The browser is Chrome running on Android.

The [Terms of Service](https://colab.research.google.com/pro/terms/v1) do not prevent access by children; on the contrary, the preamble seems specifically written to allow for the possibility of a parent entering into the agreement on behalf of a child. It seems strange that Google should provide a free resource to those wanting to learn, but deny access to children. So my question is, is something wrong with our configuration, or is this Google's policy? If the latter, what is the rationale for it? I ask this question so I can decide whether it is justified to circumvent the restriction, which appears at first sight to be technical rather than legal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming

Comment: I admit I'm confused. Google Colab, Python and Machine Learning are very much programming,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what I think that Google is doing right. As I'm also a school Student I can understand the curiosity your child is having regarding exploring cool stuff. But on the other hand, it can also be harmful to his mind.

Google collab is specially designed to collab mainly in the field of Machine Learning, Data Analysis, etc. and if your child who is just 8 years old try to do that stuff at that age then for sure he will fail to do it which can impact negatively on your child's brain and if he finds that these fields are very-difficult then for sure your child will try not to pursue a career in that field.

I understand that doing programming is good for all ages but you as a father you need to make sure that your child does not go too much into it at that age as for the child of 8 years it is really important to do physical activity also.

And the simple and direct answer to your question according to me is that - Ya, a child of 8 years old can do programming but try not to use online tools like Google Collab or online IDEs as it can distract your child.

Please also note that I'm not a psychologist, I'm answering this question because somewhere in my life I was also stuck in this situation and I preferred doing my primary tasks first and pursuing programming as a hobby. But definitely, I'll say that it totally depends on person-to-person so at the end of the day it is your choice to let it do or not.

**From the next time please don't ask these types of questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/) ask them on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)**

Comment: OK. It's just the Google help for Colab explicitly asks for them to be asked here. Hey ho.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to use Google Colab, but since I am 12 years old, the same error appeared, so I just asked my Mom to lend her account to me, and I just used it.
I mean you could lend your child your account just for that, but it's your choice.